# Редизайн интерфейса программы

Tags: delphi, интерфейс

Проект сделан на Delphi 6 и тут возник вопрос о "редизайне" интерфейса программы. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: вам не кажется что вопрос слишком общий?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "редизайном"?

Comment: Может вы имеете ввиду использование стиля кнопок винды?

Comment: @zed, поменять дизайн интерфейса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Поменяйте шрифт на segoe, если стоит MS Serif (лучше использовать системный.) в Win7-Win10 segoe. А еще лучше настройку шрифта сделать в ini файле, чтобы централизованно шрифт менялся
2. Уберите у компонентов жирную рамку (ListView, TreeView, Combobox, Edit)
3. Поменяйте иконки на иконки в стиле metro или аналогичного типа.
4. Используйте системные цвета. Смените для  clNavy другой оттенок синего, например. Раньше ссылки такого цвета были.
5. Цвет у окон белый вместо серого - раньше были ЭЛТ мониторы, окна были серого цвета - так как белый сильно выжигал пиксели на мониторах. Сейчас LCD  - это неактуально.
6. Общего плана. Сделайте компоненты и окна пошире.
7. Уберите лишние линии.
8. Линии делать более блёклыми. Вместо черного  - светлосерый. Это уменьшает визуальный перегруз. На старых мониторах серое плохо видно было, сейчас нормально (вот даже как рамка в окне редактирования вопроса/ответа на этом сайте)
9. Сделать панели плоскими. Тоже перегруз визуальный уменьшает.
10. Хинты - подсказки. Более светлым тоном (светло-серым)

Программа будет смотреться более современно и при том без замены логики UI.